# DRF Routers. Получение PK со слешами

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Задача такая:
Есть модель с pk вида `'11.22.33'`
DRF. Нужно получить эту запись по следующему URL `http://localhost/api/11/22/33/`.
Я полагаю, что нужно как-то перенастроить роутер, чтобы в PK падало значение '11/22/33/'. Дальше с выборкой queryset я разберусь.
По этому url нужен весь CRUD.
Подскажите пожалуйста.